# Generating data associated with a trend

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create 3 different datasets with a column each having dates (dd/mm/yyyy). These dates need to be in a range of 3 months like January 2019 to April 2019. The count for each date needs to represent the number of searches. The dataset should have 2000 entries and dates can be repititive as well. All 3 datasets are to be created such that one has a upward trend to the count, one has a downward trend to the count, and one is normally distributed.

```
Upward trend with the time, i.e. increasing entries with time ( lower count in beginning and increasing moving forward.)
Declining trend with time i.e. decreasing entries with time (higher count in the beginning and decreasing moving forward)
```

I am able to generate a normal distribution using datagenerator plugin of

> www.generatedata.com

I am now interested in the other 2 use cases i.e. upward trend and declining trend. Can anyone advise me how to do the same. For random distribution, I was able to achieve using the faker library as well.

```
from faker import Factory
import random
import numpy as np

faker = Factory.create()

def date_between(d1, d2):
    f = '%b%d-%Y'
    return faker.date_time_between_dates(datetime.strptime(d1, f), datetime.strptime(d2, f))

def fakerecord():
        return {'ID': faker.numerify('######'), 
                'S_date': date_between('jan01-2019', 'apr01-2019')
                }
```

Can anyone advise how can I incorporate trends to the dataset.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like below.

trend function defines your trend if start is higher than end it is downward trend and vice versa. you can also control the rate of trend by changing difference between start and end

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range("2019-1-1", "2019-4-1", freq="D")

def trend(count, start_weight=1, end_weight=3):
    lin_sp = np.linspace(start_weight, end_weight, count)
    return lin_sp/sum(lin_sp)

date_trends = np.random.choice(dates,size=20000, p=trend(len(dates)))

print("Total dates", len(date_trends))

print("counts of each dates")
print(np.unique(date_trends, return_counts=True)[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, However, this is generating only 3 dates, However I would need all the dates within the array.

Comment: So, the output needs to be 20000 entries between jan 1, 2019 to april1,2019 with the trend where the trend would incorporate the count

Comment: @vp7 I have changed the code, now it will generate all dates from between jan 1, 2019 to april1,2019. Here weight for start date is 1 which increases linearly to 3 for end date

Comment: Thank you for helping so much with this, However I am trying to write  date_trends to csv using `np.savetxt("dates.csv", date_trends, delimiter=",")` but it shows random values in the csv and not the dates, Also converting it to a dataframe is not working saying  `"IndexError: too many indices for array"`. Can you help with that

Answer (score 1):

I edited my first answer to make it more clear.

With the function below you can set the relative probabilities of generating a search on the start and end dates of your choice.

Ex. if starting_prob = 0.1 and ending_prob = 1.0, then the probability of seeing a 
search on the start date is 1/10 of the probability of seeing a search on the 
end date

If starting_prob = 1.0 and ending_prob = 0.1, then the probability of seeing a 
search on the end date is 1/10 of the probability of seeing a search on the 
start date

```
import datetime
import numpy  as np


def random_dates(start, end, starting_prob = 0.1, ending_prob = 1.0, num_samples = 2000):
    """
    Generate increasing or decreasing counts of datetimes between `start` and `end`

    Parameters:
    start: string in format'%b%d-%Y' (i.e. 'Sep19-2019')
    end : string in format'%b%d-%Y'. must be after start
    starting_prob: (float) relative probability of seeing a search on the first day
    ending_prob: (float) relative probability of seeing a search on the last day
    num_samples: number of dates in the list
    """
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%b%d-%Y')
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%b%d-%Y')

    # Get days between `start` and `end`
    num_days = (end_date - start_date).days

    linear_probabilities = np.linspace(starting_prob, ending_prob, num_days)

    # normalize probabilities so they add up to 1
    linear_probabilities /= np.sum(linear_probabilities)

    rand_days = np.random.choice(num_days, size = num_samples, replace = True,
             p = linear_probabilities)

    rand_date =  [(start_date + datetime.timedelta(int(rand_days[ii]))).strftime('%b%d-%Y') 
                  for ii in range(num_samples)]

    # return list of date strings
    return rand_date
```

You could use the function to generate different sets of dates (each with 20000 samples):

```
rdates_decreasing = random_dates("Jan01-2019", "Apr30-2019",
                      starting_prob = 1.0, ending_prob = 0.1, 
                      num_samples = 20000)

rdates_increasing = random_dates("Jan01-2019", "Apr30-2019",
                      starting_prob = 0.1, ending_prob = 1.0, 
                      num_samples = 20000)

rdates_random = random_dates("Jan01-2019", "Apr30-2019",
                      starting_prob = 1.0, ending_prob = 1.0, 
                      num_samples = 20000)
```

You can use pandas to save a csv file.  Each column will have a list of dates.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'dates_decreasing': rdates_decreasing, 
              'dates_increasing': rdates_increasing, 
              'dates_random': rdates_random, 
             }).to_csv("path\to\datefile.csv", index = False)
```

You could convert your dates to counts in a data frame like this:

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframe with counts
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"dates_decreasing": list(Counter(rdates_decreasing).keys()), 
                      "counts_decreasing": list(Counter(rdates_decreasing).values()),
                    "dates_increasing": list(Counter(rdates_increasing).keys()), 
                      "counts_increasing": list(Counter(rdates_increasing).values()),
                    "dates_random": list(Counter(rdates_random).keys()), 
                      "counts_random": list(Counter(rdates_random).values()),
                   }) 

# convert to datetime 
df1['dates_decreasing']= pd.to_datetime(df1['dates_decreasing'])
df1['dates_increasing']= pd.to_datetime(df1['dates_increasing'])
df1['dates_random']= pd.to_datetime(df1['dates_random'])


# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df1.dates_decreasing, df1.counts_decreasing, "o", label = "decreasing")
ax.plot(df1.dates_increasing, df1.counts_increasing, "o", label = "increasing")
ax.plot(df1.dates_random, df1.counts_random, "o", label = "random")
ax.set_ylabel("count")
ax.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, However, this returns me an error. I tried your function with `df = random_dates('Sep19-2019','Jan19-2020',True)` and changed the number to samples in the function to 20000 and it gives me the error `ValueError: Number of samples, -20995200, must be non-negative.`

Comment: Also, how would it incorporate the declining trend, Could you explain the function that you have written once. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I have a small question for you that you might assist me with understanding. The function certainly provide some trends, how Can we make more of a logarithmic increase  or decrease in way that it gets stagnant while it reaches the last date, for example [https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enSG856SG856&biw=1440&bih=798&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=XUKoXfToFonlvATb1Z6AAw&q=log+graphs&oq=log+graphs&gs_l=img.3..0i67j0l2j0i7i30l7.71500.71792..72117...0.0..0.131.315.1j2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.HjoVZ7eJkoY&ved=0ahUKEwi0i5X1iqPlAhWJMo8KHduqBzAQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=ZniINQblDvTnXM: ]

Comment: Sure. One way would be to replace the `linear_probabilities` with nonlinear probabilities. For example, you could import `expon` from `scipy.stats` and use an exponential CDF (cumulative distribution function) to generate the probabilities. You could replace `np.linspace(starting_prob, ending_prob, num_days)` with `expon.cdf(np.linspace(starting_prob, ending_prob, num_days), scale = 0.3)` and tune the `scale` argument to your liking

Comment: @Calin Thank you, this really helps a lot, a small question, i want to have similar trend for numerical values as well, for example, as the count increases, another variable increases in a similar order. Can I use the similar approach for the numerical value as well. if yes, How can we do that. 

Once again, thanks a lot for helping me out with this.